# Mootools doesn't fire the "onChange" event for Selects in IE7

Tags: javascript, select, events, internet-explorer-7, mootools

I'm working with MooTools 1.2.4 and I have a select with an event "change" that works fine in Firefox but when I try to test it in Internet Explorer 7 it gives me an error saying that the select doesn't have that property or method:
my code is as simple as:

```
$('zone').addEvent("change",function(E) {
    alert("change");
});
```

I've tested this code in https://www.jsfiddle.net and it does work in IE7!!! So what am I missing here? do you think that has something to do with my version of MooTools? on the MooTools more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you've created a custom version of mootools-core and forgot to include **Element.Event** in the build - http://mootools.net/core

Comment: would adding events in FF w/o that?? if so, this would be a great catch indeed :)

Comment: I've got no other explanation apart from "you're doing it wrong"

Comment: it was a problem with another JS library i was using (openlayers) I changed the order of the JS in the header of the page and now it's working fine in Firefox and IE7 =)